# mysql data transfer to mssql using trigger

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers

I want to write a trigger in mysql which take the record from mysql and insert into sql server using trigger.

Which means sql server will get update when ever mysql tables get updated using triggers.

Any one suggest me how to sync up between mysql to mssql using triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this blog post about mirrioring data between mysql and mssql.

http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/

When you have created a linked server it is easy to write the query in your triggers.